# Out of memory when storing lines from txt to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, io

I really don't know what is wrong with this, I want to read txt file ( that has ***ONLY 10*** lines at the moment) line by line and store each line in some arraylist called mChoices.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.quiz_vieaaaw);
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("questions.txt");
            BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = buffReader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
            mChoices.add(line);
            }
            inputStream.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i=0; i < mChoices.size(); i++) {
            String line = mChoices.get(i);
            Log.d("LINE", line);
        }
    }

}
```

I am getting Out of memory on a 13571696-byte allocation.

If I comment out while condition it returns me only first line, but obviously I want every line in txt.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while (line != null) {
     mChoices.add(line);
 }
```

You need to update the line each time, otherwise you will always read the first line (which is not null in your case so you're going to write an infinite times the first line until there's memory available). 
To update the line at each iteration, do :

```
String line;
while ((line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
        mChoices.add(line);
}
```

Comment: wow, cant believe I missed that xD Thanks, will accept when allowed, and thats in 10 mins